# Process coverage data and calculate the suspiciousness values based on the 4 SBFL formulae

Tags: java, debugging

I have to analyze the JFreeChart program so I can calculate the suspiciousness values based on the 4 SBFL formulae. My problem is, outside of knowing those formulae, I'm not entirely sure what my professor is asking for. I've already opened the provided folder and read the test case (first line) of each file. Now I have create the final list of source code methods with their suspiciousness values.

I don’t know what to try because I can't find any example code to know where to start (if that makes sense).